# Creating model that would take statewide parcel layer and split it into all individual parcels by counties using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.5, parcel

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5, I want to split the statewide shape into counties to speed up the process.

Is it possible to make a model that creates individual shapefiles for each county with ModelBuilder?  " Sorry I was not specific. I am working with data provided by a client that often has parcels that overun the typical public shapefiles " Edit

Comment: Why not just download the county shp for that state and work with that instead?

Comment: Sorry I was not specific. I am working with data provided by a client that often has parcels that overun the typical public shapefiles.

Comment: Please  [edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 3):

Might not need an actual model for this. If you have a county field in the parcel dataset, check out [split by attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) tool. Or use the county layer itself and split the parcels using the [split](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm) tool.